# Are there other style sheet languages than CSS?

Tags: programming-languages

So this came up in a discussion over lunch about how weird the HTML, CSS and JS triangle of web technology is. HTML is a markup language, one of many. Javascript is a programming language, one of many. However CSS is *really* weird, it's a style sheet language.

I tried googling around but I really couldn't find a lot of information about other style sheet languages. Do they exist? Are any currently used anywhere? Or is CSS really a unique little flower in the computing world?

Comment: Don't know about _languages_ (other than SCSS and LESS that compile _to_ CSS), but stylesheets as a concept exist in many word processors (Open Office and variants, MS Word).

Comment: CSS though is described as a style sheet language(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_sheet_language) It's not a _programming_ language since it misses many features of that but it is still a _language_ . What format does Open Office save its stylesheets in?

Comment: Well... if you gonna go wikipedia... why not look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_stylesheet_languages ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [DSSSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Style_Semantics_and_Specification_Language) was an inspiration behind CSS and XSLT.